# Joining two different columns in one (oretation is name )

Tags: python, pandas

I have question how can I connect two diferent columns in one for example:
A , B, C are existing df.
The column D is finale df.

```
         A        B              C             
1   Pattern     B3341        Description      
7   18774       18.11.2019       63            
8   18775       18.11.2019       63            
26  Pattern     B2633        Description      
56  18814       18.11.2019       63             
57  18815       18.11.2019       63
```

How can I get the column D:
I dont know how to write the **B3341** (first i must finde the word **Description** and than past the left row in to column D)

Output:

```
   D             
 B3341           
   63            
   63            
 B2633      
   63             
   63
```

Comment: `A`, `B`, and `C` are all _DataFrames_? Can you present the output in a way that might be easier to understand, and expand on your explanation of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Your final output doesn't make much sense

Comment: I am a new here. I want to count all  numbers '63' for diferent ID, this is the 'B3341'. But I am trying step by step I have a long list with different dimensions and IDs. But i dont know how to start :)

Comment: The point is that you don't "stack" columns like that in pandas. It's not a valid design

Comment: Agreed with @rafaelc, I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the apply function for this:

```
def custom_apply(row):
    if row['C'] == 'Description':
        return row['B']
    else:
        return row['C']

df['D'] = df.apply(custom_apply, axis=1)
```

Should work

Or even as lambda expression:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['B'] if x['C'] == 'Description' else x['C'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Are you not even going to mention that OP is clearly doing something wrong with their DataFrames?

Comment: No, why would I? OP stated a clear question and I answered it, I have no information about anything else, like where OP gets the df from etc, as far as I know OP gets the df as a return from a different function in which nothing can be changed. Clear question - clear answer

Comment: Forgot to mention that this seems like the use case for `np.where()`, although another answer already covered it.

Comment: I dont know why its woring for CSV file and for xlsx it didnt work? I think the problem are number 63? How can i solve that?

Comment: I don't know, please ask a new question for that giving all information

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where):

```
df['D'] = np.where(df['C'] == ' Description', df['B'], df['C'])
```

Or the method [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask):

```
df['D'] = df['C'].mask(df['C'] == 'Description', df['B'])
```

Comment: I dont know why its woring for CSV file and for xlsx it didnt work? I think the problem are number 63? How can I solve that?